# Object illisible in the image render of blender

Tags: blender

I have an object in blender which I download it from the Net. But when I run the render, the object doesn't exist. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rendering is turned off for that object? In the outliner, there are 3 icons: an eye, arrow, and camera. Check if the camera icon is enabled, disabling will hide that object from the render view.

Comment: I checked and I found it enabled. But I find the solution by removing the existing material and creating a new one.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad you got it to appear :)

Answer (score 0):

Which renderer are you using for your project and which renderer was the model you downloaded set up for?

If you are using Blender Internal and the model was set up for Cycles or vice-versa that could explain the issue and why creating a new material corrected it as BI and Cycles have different material setups.